# Writing a piece wise function using pgf plots

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hello I am trying to write the piece wise function:

[image]

This is my code and I don't think I'm doing it right.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    func(\t)= (1/3^k<\t \leq 1/3^k) * (3^kt-1/k)   +
              and(2/3^k < \t \leq 1/3^{k-1}) * (3-3^kt/k)     +
              (\t = 0) * (0)
   ;
  }
]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=-5, ymax=5, ytick={-5,...,5}, ylabel=$y$,
  xmin=-5, xmax=5, xtick={-5,...,5}, xlabel=$x$,
  domain=-pi:pi,samples=101, % added
]

\addplot [blue,thick] {func(t)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome! How would pgf know what `k` is? Also, you have to write `kt` as `k*t`. In order to get a good answer, provide a complete example that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and is in principle compilable, i.e. up to the specific problems you are facing.

Comment: `3^kt-1/k` (your input) is not the same as `(3^kt-1)/k` (your picture).

Answer (score 1):

You almost were there. You can't use `\leq` or other typesetting commands but you need to use `<=` here. You can't use both `<` and `<=` in the same expression either, you have to `and` those two conditions. (We could also write a PGFMath function `between`.)

Since your function is parametrized and takes two variables, *k* and *t* the PGFMath function `func` will have to take two variables, too.

Since your function only draws lines and is only defined between 1/3<sup>*k*</sup> and 1/3<sup>*k*</sup> (what's the *t* = 0 for?) I've only let it evaluate three points instead of plotting a whole function.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.18,
  utils/samples at/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}%
    \pgfkeyssetevalue{/pgfplots/samples at}
      {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/samples at},\pgfmathresult}},
  samples at evaluated/.style args={#1,#2}{
    samples at/.evaluated={#1}, utils/samples at/.list={#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    func(\k,\t)= 1/\k * (
        and(1/3^\k < \t,  \t <= 2/3^\k)     * (3^\k*\t-1)
      + and(2/3^\k < \t,  \t <= 1/3^(\k-1)) * (3-3^\k*\t));}]
\newcommand*\myK{0.2}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=0, ymax=ceil(1/\myK), ylabel=$y$,
  extra x ticks = {1/3^\myK, 2/3^\myK, 1/3^(\myK-1)},
  extra x tick labels={$1/3^k = 1/3^{\myK}$, $2/3^k = 2/3^{\myK}$,
    \pgfmathparse{\myK-1}$1/3^{k-1} = 1/3^{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$},
  extra x tick style={tick label style={rotate=90, anchor=east, scale=.5}},
  xmin=floor(1/3^\myK), xmax=ceil(1/3^(\myK-1)), xlabel=$x$,
  samples at evaluated={1/3^\myK, 2/3^\myK, 1/3^(\myK-1)},
]
\addplot [blue, thick] {func(\myK,x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me to plot piecewise functions has been the forget plot option. This pretends the previous plot has never been done for the purposes of legends/styling/etc. Here is an example for k=1.

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=-5, ymax=5, ytick={-5,...,5}, ylabel=$y$,
  xmin=-5, xmax=5, xtick={-5,...,5}, xlabel=$t$,
  domain=-pi:pi,samples=101, no markers% added
]

\addplot+[forget plot, domain=0.33:0.66] {(3*x-1)/1};
\addplot+ [forget plot, domain=0.66:1] {(3-3*x)/1};
\addplot+[domain=0:0] coordinates{(0, 0)};
\addlegendentry{Piecewise function};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Of course, you will have to determine k yourself if you don't want this to become a 3D plot.